# Extend "body" when absolute positioned element is outside the browser window

Tags: javascript, html, css

Imagine an HTML page like the following one:

```
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="free">aaa</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The `free` div is absolutely positioned, and its position is outside the visible area of the browser. Because of that, it will generate an overflow, and scrollbars will be shown. This is ok.

The `main` div, instead, should be as big as the *full* area inside the browser. It shouldn't be limited to the visible area.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%
}
.main {
    background-color: gray;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.free {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 3000px;
    top: 3000px;
}
```

As you can see here, http://jsfiddle.net/y79NS/12/, the gray div doesn't extend in the "overflow zone". It works if I add a static width/height to html and body elements, but I don't know in advance how much it should be big.

Is there a pure CSS solution? If not, what's the best way to do it with Javascript, keeping in mind that the user could resize the browser in any moment?

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing a semi-colon in your CSS, also use negative margins if you want to hide `.free`:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
 position: relative;
}
.main {
    background-color: gray;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.free {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    left: -3000px;
    top: -3000px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/btipling/y79NS/17/

Comment: I need the "free" div to be in that position :P The user must be able to scroll and find it.

Comment: As far as I know you can't use absolute positioning that way. Absolute positioning takes the element out of the flow. Make `.main` the height and width you want the area to be, and then position your `.free` instead of it.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning

Comment: In that case, it looks like the best thing to do is to set the `min-width` and `min-height` of `.main` to something that matches the position of `.free`. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/y79NS/25/
Note how shrinking the window will led to an overflow that is always covered by `.main`.
The only problem is that, if the position of `.free` is dynamic, I have to update `min-width` and `min-height` from javascript.

Comment: I don't understand what it is you are trying to do. Is this a game? Consider keeping track of x and y coordinates inside memory instead of inside the document state. Use game controls instead of scrollbars. Then you don't have to worry about square peg in a round hole type of issues.

Comment: It's something very similar to a MDI: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_document_interface